# Do we really need Cache Memory?

Tags: caching, architecture, ram, cpu-architecture

Now a days the speed of RAM is 2400MHz (DDR4 RAM), and if the speed of the processor is 1.6 GHz, then do we really need cache memory?

Comment: I'd say this question is probably off-topic here but, anyway, think about another factor: **latency**. Another thing is that main memory is _shared_ between processes/threads while cache has a better **locality** (remember that each cpu/core/alu operate in parallel while memory has to synchronize access between them). All these said...any modern CPU has much **higher frequency** than 1.6 GHz...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Thank you for clearing my Doubt

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, Latency is closely tied with bandwidth as well - the shorter the request is, the more parallel requests you can support per a given time frame, since you have a limited number of buffers for outstanding requests.